# DANTED SERVER v1.1.19 - Error configuration sock5 on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

i have follow this tutorial [dante sock5 configuration](https://www.binarytides.com/setup-dante-socks5-server-on-ubuntu/) and i have a strange error.

Below are my danted.conf file :

```
# /etc/danted.conf

logoutput: syslog
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody

# The listening network interface or address.
internal: 0.0.0.0 port=1080

# The proxying network interface or address.
external: eth0

# socks-rules determine what is proxied through the external interface.
# The default of "none" permits anonymous access.
socksmethod: username

# client-rules determine who can connect to the internal interface.
# The default of "none" permits anonymous access.
clientmethod: none

client pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect disconnect error
}
socks pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect disconnect error
}
```

when i start the dante service i have this error message :

```
Starting Dante SOCKS daemon: Nov 21 13:38:09 (1542803889) danted[21175]: /etc/danted.conf: error on line 15, near 's': syntax error
```

the error is localised on the line "socksmethod: username".

i dont know how to resolve it ....i dont even know where to start my investigation...

[NOW]

**I have resolved configuration error**, below my config file

```
# /etc/danted.conf

logoutput: syslog
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody

# The listening network interface or address.
internal: 0.0.0.0 port=1080

# The proxying network interface or address.
external: eth0

# socks-rules determine what is proxied through the external interface.
# The default of "none" permits anonymous access.
method: username

# client-rules determine who can connect to the internal interface.
# The default of "none" permits anonymous access.
method: none

socks pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect disconnect error
}
```

but now my connection is **refused**

```
curl -v -x socks5://login:password@ip_adress:1080 http://www.google.com/
*   Trying XX.XX.YYY.ZZZ...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to XX.XX.YYY.ZZZ port 1080 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to XX.XX.YYY.ZZZport port 1080: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to XX.XX.YYY.ZZZport port 1080: Connection refused
```

my firewall is **totally opened** !!

for the moment i did not understand why there are "client pass" and "socks pass"  ....

maybe the error is there !

Please help !!

Thanks all !

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this config file.

check danted-servier version

```
danted -v
```

danted-server V1.1

```
internal: eth0  port = 1080
external: eth0
external.rotation: same-same
socksmethod: pam.username none
clientmethod: none
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: sock
logoutput: /var/log/danted.log
client pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}
client block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}
socks pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}
socks block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}
```

Because you danted-server version to old,You can also try new version danted-server.
There are some differences between the old and new versions of the configuration files.

danted-server V1.4

```
logoutput: /var/log/socks.log
internal: eth0 port = 1080
external: eth0
clientmethod: none
socksmethod: none
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody

client pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}
client block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}
socks pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}
socks block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}
```

Note that the log file needs to be created first.

```
sudo touch /var/log/socks.log
```

(No account password is added to any of the above profiles,You can change serivce port XD)